# QEMU network configuration

Tags: c, operating-system, qemu

I hope it is not a tedious question. I am working on a school project right now, basically making an OS. We use a QEMU as an emulator for linux env on Windows and test our OS on the other QEMU. Ok, so I saw that with default design, the guest network will be NAT which cannot receive any packets from outside. 
I googled the solution and did find a few but it seems does not work. Here are situation I have encountered:

1. In QEMU monitor, I try netdev_add, net_add, only user mode can be used. tap and the others are not included
2. I don't where to add those command like -net, -netdev to. I saw similar code in QEMU executable file's properties. I add those command and it simply does not open.
3. I cannot find those config files because in the QEMU source folders, I can only find executable, rom, ddl, linux kernel folder for linux env but not document file.
4. I did successfully use **hostfwd_add 0** **127.0.0.1:5555-:5556** in monitor but when I use netstat cmd, the activated TCP is **0.0.0.0:***. When I use a python TCP link to 127.0.0.1, python reports fail to connect.

Is there anything I did wrong here and what I should do to finish this network config?

Comment: 2. add them to QEMU executable in `cmd` session to see what errors you get